# Can't connect to MySQL database error

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting MYSQL ERROR from my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765675/getting-mysql-error-from-my-site)

I have hosted a bux site CrimsonBux.Com. Everything is working fantastic with the script. I have only one problem with Password Recovery Page http://crimsonbux.com/login.php?option=forgot. After entering Email address and CAPTCHA on the page, users are getting redirected to this page http://crimsonbux.com/recover.php. In recover.php page users are facing errors. The errors are listed below.

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'crimst1d'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/crimst1d/public_html/recover.php on line 19

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/crimst1d/public_html/recover.php on line 19
```

Here my site is not being able to connect to MySQL database. How to connect?

Here is my configuration of recover.php page.

```
<?
/**********************************************************************************************************************************************
    ScriptBux Version 2.50 beta
    This Script has been created and coded by Gabrola and edited by hassan ahmady.
    If you find any bugs in the script report at support@thealternatif.info or contact hassan ahmady.
    Copywrite ScriptBux 2008;
    Please make donations if you use this sript for commercial use
    to My paypal account "bisnis-usd@plasa.com"
************************************************************************************************************************************************/

?>

<h3>Forgot Password</h3>
<?php
if($_POST)
{
  $code = $_POST["code"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $emailx = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tb_users WHERE email='{$_POST['email']}'");
  $emailx = mysql_fetch_array($emailx);
  $emailx = $emailx["cnt"];
  $errormsg = false;
  if($_SESSION['string'] != $code)
  {
    $error = 1;
    $errormsg .= "<b>Error -</b> The captcha was entered incorrectly.<br />";
  }
  if(!$code)
  {
    $error = 1;
    $errormsg .= "<b>Error -</b> The captcha was entered incorrectly.<br />";
  }
  if(!$email)
  {
    $error = 1;
    $errormsg .= "<b>Error -</b> The email was not supplied.<br />";
  }
  if(!$emailx)
  {
    $error = 1;
    $errormsg .= "<b>Error -</b> No account was found with that email address.<br />";
  }
  if($_SESSION['next_reseptsend'] != 0)
  {
    $error = 1;
    $errormsg .= "<b>Error -</b> You have already made a password retrieval within the last 15 minutes.<br />";
  }
  $_SESSION['string'] = false;
  if($error)
  {
    print $errormsg."<br><br>";
  } else {
    $s = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE email='{$_POST['email']}'");
    $x = mysql_fetch_array($s);
    $_SESSION['next_reseptsend'] = 1;
    $message = "Hello {$x['username']},
    You requested to resend your account password a while ago.

    Account Username: {$x['username']}
    Account Password: {$x['password']}

    We hope you can have a good time earning your money again,

    Thanks,
    {$config['site_name']}";
    mail($x["email"],"Password Retrieval - ".$config["site_name"],$message,"From: mail@".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    print "<b>Password Sent!</b><br />
    We have dispatched your password to your email address.<br />
    You can only make another account retrieval again in 15 minutes.<br />";
  }
}
?>

<div style="padding-left:25px;">
<form action="recover.php" method="post" name="resend">
<table>
<tr><td class="midtext">Your Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" size="25" class="form" autocomplete="off" value="<?=$_POST['email']?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="midtext" valign="top">Security Code:</td><td class="midtext"><img src="image.php" onclick="this.src='image.php?newtime=' + (new Date()).getTime();"><br /><span style="font-size:10px;">(Click to reload)</span><br /><input type="text" name="code" size="17" maxlength="" autocomplete="off" class="form"></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td align="right"><input type="submit" value="Login" name="loginsubmit"  class="inputbox"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>

<?php

?>
```

Comment: I want only acceptable answers that will solve my problem. Please help.

Comment: where do you connect to the database?

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) article will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here](http://goo.gl/vFWnC) is a good PDO-related tutorial.

Comment: I wouldn't pay for that script if I were you - your first `mysql_query` has a SQL injection vulnerability. Edit: if you are not the author of that script, please get in touch with them, and advise them their work is not secure.

Comment: Show the code in recover.php on line 19. You are connecting to a database and include the connection code as well.

Comment: @halfer what should I currently do with mysql_query line to solve the problem?

Comment: Oops, I see you've posted the web address as well. I recommend you get those holes plugged pronto `:(`

Comment: Aside: I was curious incidentally as to what a _bux_ site is. I suspect this is a misspelling of the US phrase 'bucks', and (so I learn) is a type of website where users are paid to watch adverts of products/services they presumably have no intention of buying. Now this isn't click-fraud exactly, but if my online advertising budget were being burnt up this way, I'd not be at all happy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a user to your database and also a database that your script can connect to via [`mysql_connect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) and [`mysql_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php).

Place on the top of your script:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database name');
```

Comment: I tried using $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
  mysql_select_db("mydb"); before mysql_query suggested by some people but still nothing seems to be changed. Please help.

Comment: I have only 1 mysql database and 1 user. Should I have to make another one for this? If yes, then should I create 1 user or database or both?

Comment: saved and reuploaded? @MorningStar

Comment: yes done it. But nothing seems to change. please help me.

Comment: Does your database have the *appropriate* tables? Explain what errors you are seeing again.

Comment: JUST TELL ME WHAT TO CHANGE OR ADD IN THE SCRIPT TO MAKE THE SCRIPT WORKING.

Comment: ^ Ha, @MorningStar - why are you shouting at someone who is helping you? You need to be a great deal more polite than that to be deserving of free technical advice (+1).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to solve your security vulnerabilities. Change this:

```
$emailx = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tb_users WHERE email='{$_POST['email']}'");
```

to this:

```
$emailUntainted = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$emailx = mysql_query("
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM tb_users
    WHERE email='{$emailUntainted}'
");
```

You have two of these to fix; do some reading as well, to *understand* why this is necessary `:)`.

Post script: as @Esailija says, it is better to use PDO and *prepared statements*, but that will take more learning on your part. Get this fix in quickly, then switch to PDO when you can.

Comment: Ok. You told i have two of those to fix. Is this the other one     $s = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE email='{$_POST['email']}'");
?

Comment: Yes, that's right. So swap the `'{$_POST['email']}'` for `'{$emailUntainted}'` in the same way.